# Formula for CGPointApplyAffineTransform function in iOS

Tags: ios, math, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d, affinetransform

I am trying to affine rotate matrix in Android based on iOS Code

iOS has two functions `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` and `CGPointApplyAffineTransform` used for calculation

```
Step 1: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation();

Input: 

2.2860321998596191

Result: 
a = -0.65579550461444569, 
b = 0.75493857771840255, 
c = -0.75493857771840255, 
d = -0.65579550461444569, 
tx = 0, ty = 0

Formula: 

double A = Math.cos(RadiansRotated);

double B = -Math.sin(RadiansRotated);

double C = Math.sin(RadiansRotated);

double D = Math.cos(RadiansRotated);
```

I am able to calculate a,b,c,d for step 1 using above formula

```
Step 2: CGPointApplyAffineTransform()

Input : 

x = 612.55191924649432, 
y = -391.95960729287646
And Matrix return from Step 1

Result: 
x = -105.80336653205421, 
y = 719.48442314773808
```

Does anyone know the formula used in ApplyAffineTransform?

## I need help for Step 2

I have tried with Android's Matrix class - Not Working

I have also tried with Java's AffineTransform - Not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math behind the `CGAffineTransform` functions is described in [“The Math Behind the Matrices” in the *Quartz 2D Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-CJBECIAD).

The formulae for transforming a point using an affine transform are given as:

> x' = ax + cy + t<sub>x</sub>
>   y' = bx + dy + t<sub>y</sub>

Incidentally, in your step 1, you have reversed the signs of b and c, which has the effect of reversing the direction of rotation.